# Basic Algebra Issue

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

[image]

I have the equation $y+1 = \frac14x^2$.
I tried to solve for $x$ (as seen in the picture). Please explain why only the right method is correct, and the left is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: The right hand side is fine, the left hand side *would* have been fine had you remembered that when applying the square root to both sides, you include **everything** on that side in the square root, including the coefficients.  Taking the square root of $\frac{1}{4}x^2$ yields $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}x^2}$  not $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: Non of the are correct.The reason is $a=\frac{4}{b^2}\implies a=\frac{|b|}{2}$ and not $\frac{b}{4}$ nor $\frac{b}{2}$.

Comment: @Surb The absolute value would only come into play if the sign is important. Here it is not.

Answer (score 2):

It should be $\sqrt{y+1}=\color{red}{\frac12}x$. When taking square roots the constants must be rooted as well.

Comment: It should be $\sqrt{y+1}=\frac{|x|}{2}$.

Comment: @Surb Not important for the question's purposes.

Comment: yes it's important !

Comment: @Surb Important only if you are pedantic, or need to be.

Comment: As you wrote you mean $\frac{1}{4}=\frac{(-1)^2}{4}\implies \frac{1}{2}=\frac{-1}{2}$. Maybe for you is not a problem, but this is simply wrong.

Comment: @Surb You are being too pedantic. I understand what you mean, but if it is said that $2\sqrt{y+1}=x$ is "correct", then the question here is asking why the other branch is incorrect. It is not asking whether each option is correct by itself.

Comment: That's why it's (at my opinion) necessary to point to the OP that this step of his calcul is wrong as well, and not only the mistake with the square root. (and sorry if you feel that I'm pedantic, I just point something that is wrong).